# Java Keywords as a variable

Tags: java, variables

In VB.NET, we can surround a variable name with brackets and use keywords as variable names, like this:

```
Dim [new] As String = ""
```

C# equivalent:

```
string @new = "";
```

I was wondering is there a Java equivalent to doing this?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wanted to have a variable called "old", and a variable called "new", then i stumbled upon this question

Comment: While it is possible in some languages, I'm pretty sure there's a special place in hell for people who do this. There's a lower level reserved for people who do this when creating SQL objects.

Comment: @Carth what sql objects?

Comment: As in creating a table named [table]. As you've pointed out, there are ways in some languages to get around the keyword protection but it's a bad idea to do so. If you're writing a non-trivial program you're almost guaranteed to create hard to find bugs. You'll also end up driving some maintenance programmer crazy in the future.

Comment: @Carth In a language like C# or Java I'm struggling to imagine any case where you could accidentally use a keyword instead of a variable and it'd still compile. Being able to name a variable "class" if you're building a school's timetabling system is nice, and as far as I can tell, completely safe.

Comment: Incapable Java... Go back to use C# :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. You can add an underscores or somesuch nonsense, but basically keywords are off limits.

Answer (score 4):

Tricks like `goTo` and `goto_` are, of course, possible.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of java.

The simple answer is , that is not possible.

Please read the specification for declaring variable names

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html

Tut on variable declaration.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

List of banned keywords that should be used as variables .
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Cheers and keep learning!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Java keywords as variables, method or class names.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Although you can do horrible things like this:

```
String String = "String";
```

If you wanted to be evil, you could use a unicode character and fake it.

Comment: what are you talking about, surely unicode characters can't be used for variable names?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's why I said "Nope."

Comment: @Pacerier [Sure they can.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#40625)

Comment: @Kane That's why I said "Nope."

Answer (score 0):

you can use the keyword `@SerializedName("keyword")`. it will map Json node to the keyword specified when you receive a response from the server.